# Click through div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When on notification hover, i want it to make opacity to semi transparent and being able to click through it like in this notification plugin Pines Notify

I tried using `pointer-events:none`, but then it disables DOM element, so jQuery isn't working on this element. I need jQuery to execute code when on hover and on hover out. How can it be done ?

Answer (score 6):

To be able to click through a div use the following

1. Hide the overlay div
2. trigger a click on the covered element
3. show the div again

http://jsfiddle.net/H6UEU/1/

```
$('#front-div').click(function (e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)).trigger("click");
    $(this).show();
});
$(".tobeclicked").click(function(){
    $("#result").append("clicked<br />");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a combination of applying the `:hover` selector to the parent div and the `pointer-events: none` directive on the child div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8erCP/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="clickthrough">Mouseover</div>
    <button onClick="alert('click!');">Click me</button>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.clickthrough {
    position: absolute;
}

.container:hover .clickthrough {
    opacity: 0.25;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how:

```
$(".above").click(function(e) {
    // Hide the element so we can reach the element below.
    $(this).hide(0);

    // Fetch the underlying element.
    var below = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));

    // Trigger a click on the underlying element at the earliest convenience.
    setTimeout(function() {
        below.trigger("click");
    });

    // Display the element again.
    $(this).show(0);
});

$(".below").click(function() { alert("Below clicked!"); });
```

The `setTimeout` block makes the topmost element reappear before the click event on the underlying element.

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/t86aV/

Answer (score 0):

What if to use inner DIV with high z-index? 
For example:

```
<style>
    .sub {
        position: relative;
        background: #99f;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .top {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .opacityLayer {
        position: absolute;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        left: 30px;
        top: 30px;
    }
</style>
<a href="#"><div class="sub"><div class="top"></div></div></a>
<div class="opacityLayer"></div>
```