# Can I combine a Jquery hover zoom div with an imagemap?

Tags: jquery, html, zooming, imagemap, pointer-events

It looks like some old questions may have been sort of similar to mine, but I don't think anything's really hit the mark yet.

[Here's my site.](http://inthyorisons.boards.net/) View source at will. As you can see, I've got a little magnifier effect going on for the map that I want to keep, but I also want to have this function as an imagemap as well, where clicking on a region will take you there.

My skill level is pretty beginner, guys, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that. Is there some fanangly way to make this happen?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Just thought I should add -- from what I understand, the problem is that a) I haven't figured out a way / there is no way to have the imagemap somehow correspond to my little floating magnifying glass and b) the magnifying glass div blocks the cursor from clicking on the base (smaller) image, so putting the imagemap on that one won't work. That's about as far as I've gotten on my own, though.

Comment: Okay, sort of got it working with pointer-events, but the action's a little sticky. Any way to smooth this out, or do it differently in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question! [Click through div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642247/click-through-div)

The javascript in Sam B.'s answer to the above linked question works effectively in the way I wanted, AND it's much, much smoother action than the pointer-effects gave me. I'm so happy! Thanks to everyone who looked at this answer. If I had more reputation, I'd upvote Sam's suggestion, but that'll have to wait, I guess. ^^;