# touch event and mouse event in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch, touch-event

**1) I'm building a very normal HTML5 website.**

On this website there are few clickable elements. Those are embedded in multi-layer div.

[HAML](http://haml.info/) speaking it looks as :

```
%body
  #root
    #content
  #header
  #footer
```

In my div `#content` I have few clickable buttons. Some dragable elements. And video players.

-> this make use of mouse events as `click`, `mousemove`, `mouseenter` ...

**2) I'm adding a touch gesture detection**

Everything is fine until I want to add a layer (a div) to catch touch gestures.

Then I obtains this :

```
%body
  #root
    #content
  #header
  #footer
  #touch-area
```

This `#touch-area` size of the window is capable to interpret user touch gesture via `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchstop`

**3) cool! but I'm loosing control of mouse events**

The issue with this construction is *all mouse events are caught by `#touch-area`*

I've tried few «hacks»

3.1) via CSS

adding [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to `#touch-area` disable touch event at same time.

3.2) What is it possible in JS?

Reading [Click through div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642247/click-through-div) . The guy add a `click` listener to top div. Hide this div. Re-trigger the event. Re-show the div.

It could work but:

- it use jQuery
- I've to specify all events I want to let pass trough my `#touch-area`

3.3) ok, let's focus on `mousemove`

So I read this [post about HTML5 and touchscreen](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/). And I found this interesting event order :

> ```
> 1. touchstart
> 2. touchmove
> 3. touchend
> 4. mouseover
> 5. mousemove
> 6. mousedown
> 7. mouseup
> 8. click
> ```

And I though:

- *First* I add `mousemove` listenner to `#touch-area`. Where I hide `#touch-area`.
- *Then* all events will go though.
- *And* on side I add a timeout routine to show `#touch-area` after few ms. That to catch again touch events.

But... when I swipe on the touchscreen. It first detect few `mousemove`. Then the sequence `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchstop` is fired.

begin log of event on `#touch-area` when I swipe my finger :

(*event name* followed by *event time*)

> ```
> mouse enter
> 1490656039478
> mouse move
> 1490656039479
> mouse enter
> 1490656039483
> mouse move
> 1490656039484
> touch start
> 1490656039485
> touch move
> 1490656039492
> touch move
> 490656039498
> ```

... then there is only `touch move` until `touch stop`

so my plan is broken :(

**4) stackoverflow could you help me?**

How to have a top layer capable to catch touch gestures and bellow normal clickable buttons?

Comment: mikro, I really appreciate the effort you put into composing your question but, at least for me, it's not really clear what you are asking. And I don't think I should have to read all the resources you linked in order to understand that. Could you please state in clear what you want to achieve? In 20 words, or less? Maybe also provide a [mcve], if you think it could help understand the problem?

Comment: Do you want this [`functionality`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18642544/1891677) without using jQuery? Would that answer your question?

Comment: I understand. That why I attempt to put a "simple" question at point 4. The complexity is behind what is exposed at point 2. Close enough I believe to "Minimal exemple". To finish I described my tries at point 3.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, no as it the answer with jQuery will not solve my issue.

Comment: mikro, can you please re-read my previous question? I specifically asked "without jQuery". If I make a pure js script that on click disables pointer events on `#touch-area`, clicks again in the same spot and than re-enables pointer events on `#touch-area`, that's not going to help you?

Answer (score 1):

This will allow clicks to pass through `#touch-area`, without using `jQuery`:

```js
let touchArea = document.getElementById('touch-area');
touchArea.onclick = function(e){
  touchArea.style.display = 'none';
  document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).click();
  touchArea.style.display = 'block';
  return false;
}
```

Working [`example`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zmdgrtyu/). While it works for `click`s, having it work for hover is a completely different matter and frankly, I have no idea on how you could achieve that.

Comment: nice :) But that's not including hover events which are showing to user what is clickable via the pointer and sometime with visual emphasis. That's why I was more focusing on `mousemove`. Anyway so far the best option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply check the device for touch support, and only then insert the #touch-area div dynamically?

My goto solution for evaluating if a device supports feature x is https://modernizr.com/.

Here's a quick intro to using Modernizr to identifying the devices that support touch events, and those that don't: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-touch-device-modernizr/

Comment: I do not add #touch-aera dynamically for touch device because all "tap"/"click" are described layers below. And I need it even with touch devices. But the idea is there. I attempted to hide #touch-area when it not a specific gesture (swipe, pan).

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `preventDefault()` method in the touch event handlers.

[Supporting Touch and Mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent)